# Radio button checked property not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a `div` on which I am appending a `table` which has `input` of type `radio`. After it get rendered, Its checked property is not changing while I click it. What could be the problem?

```
<input type="radio" id="radHalf0" name="grp0" class="half">
```

**Update 1**

I am using `Jquery.Ajax` to create `Markup` as below

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Leave-Application.aspx/CreateTable",
                    data: "{'dates':'" + formattedDateArray + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $("#tblLeaveDetails").html("");
                        $("#tblLeaveDetails").append(msg.d);
                        $("#divLeaveDetails").fadeIn();
                        $("#divTotal").fadeIn();
                    }
                });



[WebMethod]
        public static string CreateTable(string dates)
        {
            string[] dateArray = dates.Split(',');
            StringBuilder markup = new StringBuilder("<table class='table table-striped table-hover table-bordered' style='width: 435px'>");
            markup.Append(@" <tr> <th>Date</th> <th>Half Day</th> <th>Full Day</th></tr>");

            for (int i = 0; i < dateArray.Length; i++)
            {
                string rowid = dateArray[i].Replace('/', '-');
                markup.Append(" <tr id = " + rowid + "> <td>" + dateArray[i] + "</td>");
                markup.Append("  <td><input type=\"radio\" id=\"radHalf" + i + "\" name=\"grp" + i + "\" class=\"half\"/></td>");
                markup.Append("  <td><input type=\"radio\" id=\"radFull" + i + "\" name=\"grp" + i + "\" class=\"full\"/></td></tr>");
            }
            markup.Append("</table>");
            return markup.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Please post your full code

Comment: The input elements must have the same name?

Comment: @ZhivkoDonev they has infact

Comment: @Imad then we will need more of your code to be able to help you.

Comment: @Imad the code seems to be ok. How do you check for the checked property? Inspecting the html or with jQuery? If you are inspecting the html you won't see the changed property while with javascript/jQuery you will - $('input[type=radio]:checked'). If this is not the case there might be some eventHandler that stops event propagation on click event.

Comment: yes, I was doing that stupid thing :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a single radio box, it won't change. If you are using single change it to a chekcbox instead.
Also if you have multiple radio boxes make sure they have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating radio buttons which have different ID (as well name). Since there is only one radio button of that Id and name , it cannot be un-selected. Remove + i + that you are appending for Id and name. If All of them are diff and if they can be selected and unselected then use checkbox instead of radio buttons.